# PowerShell FINDSTR eqivalent?

Tags: search, powershell

What's the DOS FINDSTR equivalent for [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)? I need to search a bunch of log files for "ERROR".

Comment: There's a website with a good article for this: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2006/06/03/pshfindstr

Answer (score 36):

Here's the quick answer

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.log | select-string ERROR
```

I found it [here](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2006/06/03/pshfindstr) which has a great indepth answer!

Answer (score 9):

For example, find all instances of "#include" in the c files in this directory and all sub-directories.

```
gci -r -i *.c | select-string "#include"
```

gci is an alias for get-childitem

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on Monroecheeseman's answer.  gci is an alias for Get-ChildItem (which is the equivalent to dir or ls), the -r switch does a recursive search and -i means include.

Piping the result of that query to select-string has it read each file and look for lines matching a regular expression (the provided one in this case is ERROR, but it can be any .NET regular expression).

The result will be a collection of match objects, showing the line matching, the file, and and other related information.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($entry.EntryType -eq "Error")
```

Being Object Oriented, you want to test the property in question with one of the standard comparison operators you can find [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_syntax.htm#Operators_).

I have a [PS script](http://slipsec.blogspot.com/2008/04/monitoring-remote-event-logs-from.html) watching logs remotely for me right now - some simple modification should make it work for you.

edit: I suppose I should also add that is a cmdlet built for this already if you don't want to unroll the way I did.  Check out:

```
man Get-EventLog
Get-EventLog -newest 5 -logname System -EntryType Error
```

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, here's a search that will list all the files containing a particular regex search or string.  It could use some improvement so feel free to work on it.  Also if someone wanted to encapsulate it in a function that would be welcome.

I'm new here so if this should go in it's own topic just let me know.  I figured I'd put it her since this looks mostly related.

```
# Search in Files Script
# ---- Set these before you begin ---- 
$FolderToSearch="C:\" # UNC paths are ok, but remember you're mass reading file contents over the network
$Search="Looking For This" # accepts regex format
$IncludeSubfolders=$True #BUG: if this is set $False then $FileIncludeFilter must be "*" or you will always get 0 results
$AllMatches=$False
$FileIncludeFilter="*".split(",") # Restricting to specific file types is faster than excluding everything else
$FileExcludeFilter="*.exe,*.dll,*.wav,*.mp3,*.gif,*.jpg,*.png,*.ghs,*.rar,*.iso,*.zip,*.vmdk,*.dat,*.pst,*.gho".split(",")

# ---- Initialize ----
if ($AllMatches -eq $True) {$SelectParam=@{AllMatches=$True}}
else {$SelectParam=@{List=$True}}
if ($IncludeSubfolders -eq $True) {$RecurseParam=@{Recurse=$True}}
else {$RecurseParam=@{Recurse=$False}}

# ---- Build File List ---- 
#$Files=Get-Content -Path="$env:userprofile\Desktop\FileList.txt" # For searching a manual list of files
Write-Host "Building file list..." -NoNewline
$Files=Get-ChildItem -Include $FileIncludeFilter -Exclude $FileExcludeFilter -Path $FolderToSearch -ErrorAction silentlycontinue @RecurseParam|Where-Object{-not $_.psIsContainer} # @RecurseParam is basically -Recurse=[$True|$False]
#$Files=$Files|Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Select the Files to Search' # Manually choose files to search, requires powershell 3.0
Write-Host "Done"

# ---- Begin Search ---- 
Write-Host "Searching Files..."
$Files|
    Select-String $Search @SelectParam| #The @ instead of $ lets me pass the hastable as a list of parameters.  @SelectParam is either -List or -AllMatches
    Tee-Object -Variable Results|
    Select-Object Path
Write-Host "Search Complete"
#$Results|Group-Object path|ForEach-Object{$path=$_.name; $matches=$_.group|%{[string]::join("`t", $_.Matches)}; "$path`t$matches"} # Show results including the matches separated by tabs (useful if using regex search)

<# Other Stuff
    #-- Saving and restoring results
    $Results|Export-Csv "$env:appdata\SearchResults.txt" # $env:appdata can be replaced with any UNC path, this just seemed like a logical place to default to
    $Results=Import-Csv "$env:appdata\SearchResults.txt"

    #-- alternate search patterns
    $Search="(\d[-|]{0,}){15,19}" #Rough CC Match
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to do this:

```
gci <the_directory_path> -filter *.csv | where { $_.OpenText().ReadToEnd().Contains("|") -eq $true }
```

This helped me find all csv files which had the `|` character in them.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell has basically precluded the need for *findstr.exe* as the previous answers demonstrate. Any of these answers should work fine.

However, **if you actually need to use *findstr.exe*** (as was my case) here is a PowerShell wrapper for it:

Use the `-Verbose` option to output the *findstr* command line.

---

```
function Find-String
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Path')]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string]
        $Pattern,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Path', Mandatory=$false, Position=1, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]]
        $Path,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='LiteralPath', Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias('PSPath')]
        [string[]]
        $LiteralPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]
        $IgnoreCase,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]
        $UseLiteral,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]
        $Recurse,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]
        $Force,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]
        $AsCustomObject
    )

    begin
    {
        $value = $Pattern.Replace('\', '\\\\').Replace('"', '\"')

        $findStrArgs = @(
            '/N'
            '/O'
            @('/R', '/L')[[bool]$UseLiteral]
            "/c:$value"
        )

        if ($IgnoreCase)
        {
            $findStrArgs += '/I'
        }

        function GetCmdLine([array]$argList)
        {
            ($argList | foreach { @($_, "`"$_`"")[($_.Trim() -match '\s')] }) -join ' '
        }
    }

    process
    {
        $PSBoundParameters[$PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName] | foreach {
            try
            {
                $_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse:$Recurse -Force:$Force -ErrorAction Stop | foreach {
                    try
                    {
                        $file = $_
                        $argList = $findStrArgs + $file.FullName

                        Write-Verbose "findstr.exe $(GetCmdLine $argList)"

                        findstr.exe $argList | foreach {
                            if (-not $AsCustomObject)
                            {
                                return "${file}:$_"
                            }

                            $split = $_.Split(':', 3)

                            [pscustomobject] @{
                                File = $file
                                Line = $split[0]
                                Column = $split[1]
                                Value = $split[2]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI:
If you update to Powershell version 7 you can use grep...
I know egrep is in powershell on Azure CLI...
But SS is there!
An old article here:  [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/select-string-and-grep/]