# Findstr doesn't recognize string on first line (Encoding UTF-8 BOM)

Tags: utf-8, findstr, byte-order-mark

I need to remove lines containing ":setvar" (case insensitive) in thousands of files.

It all works untill the string is on the first line.

The file is encoded UTF-8 bom.

Re-encoding the files is not an option.

Also, no 3rd party tools allowed except windows 10 stock.

Screenshot: [OriginalFile.sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Znz7N.png)

I have tried using:

findstr /v /i /b ":setvar" "OriginalFile.sql" > "TempFile.sql"

Comment: `/b` works as expected: if the file has a BOM then `:setvar` is not at the start of the line anymore. Having Win10 consider using the PowerShell ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708/powershell-findstr-eqivalent))

Comment: Thank You AmigoJack, will look into it some more.